# Changing the numbers in a list to half their value

Tags: list, mutation

I'm trying to change the numbers in a list from any given list to half their values. I do not know what the list is going to be when I start, just need to assert that the function is working after.

Here is what I have so far:

def halve_values(a):
for index in range(len(a)):
index /= 2
return index

a = [1, 2, 3]
print(halve_values(a))

The problem for me is that the list can be changed so I cannot define list a at the beginning. The program has to work if the list is given after for example:
a = [1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 13]

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def half_values(a):
     return [x/2 for x in a]

a = [1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 13]
b=half_values(a)

print(b)
```

Comment: It must pass an assertion test so I must create some kind of a loop

print("Testing halve_values... ", end="")
a = [1, 2, 3]
halve_values(a)
assert([0.5, 1, 1.5] == a)
print("OK")

Comment: please  explain a bit more , you want to half each of the element then compare it with original list?

Comment: I need to half the integers in any given list of numbers, for example:
a = [1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 13]
must become:
a = [0.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 6.5]

Comment: please refer to updated answer, is that what you want?

Comment: I cannot call the new list b, I must mutate a list a within a loop so when I call for assert half_values(a) it will return the list a with half integers in it :(

Comment: OK, I changed some things around now it works! Thanks

Comment: great ! thought we were bit unclear , please  provide updated answer so other can be benefited

Answer (score 0):

def half_values(a):
return [x/2 for x in a]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).